# sql database a panda

Tags: python, sql

hello someone can help me I must create a program in Python that connects to my database, read the database records and create a pivot table with Pandas with that data

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for [pandas.read_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html#pandas-read-sql)

You can use `con` parameter to pass your database connection string.

Comment: i am new using database , i am using applications like sql workbench 8.0 and heidisql
they recommended us to have the libraries (Mysql, Python, dash libraries, panda, pymysql)
and the assignment they gave me is create a program in Python that connects to my database, read the database records and create a pivot table with Pandas with that data

can you help me with an example code?

Comment: examples are given in the documentation towards the end